# how can I prevent scrolling to top of page when clicking load more button

Tags: jquery, html

I have a small albeit annoying dilemna.
I have a button that will load more data when clicked, But each time the button is clicked it scrolls to the top of the page.
How can I keep the position and then add more data below.

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="loadMore" onclick="loadstuff(); return false;">Load More Results</button>

 $("#loadMore").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();    
     $("#insert_data").append(divhtml);
 });
```

I have a Jquery call that grabs the data from the database 10 items at a time.
I've tried e.preventDefault(); as well as return false; but still will not work.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does loadstuff() do? Can you post its code as well?

Comment: loadstuff() is a function that grabs the data required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```js
divhtml ="Test Test Test"

divhtml2 ="Test2 Test2 Test2"
function loadstuff(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  $("#insert_data").append(divhtml);
}

function loadstuff2(event){
  
  $("#insert_data").append(divhtml2);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.Some Text to make some space, to see the "not scrolling up" effect.

<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="loadMore" onclick="loadstuff(event)">Load More Results</a>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="loadMore" onclick="loadstuff2(event)">Load More Results 2</a>

<span id="insert_data"></span>
```

You need to pass the variable `event` in `onclick` -> pass it to a JS function and then `event.prevent...`. You also had a weird twist, when you give an element the attribute `onclick` a `$("#loadMore").click(...` does not make any sense. You simply write the `loadstuff()` function in JS it will get triggered through the `onclick`attribute.

I made two buttons so you can see the difference. With and without `event.preventDefault()`. I used `<a>` tags but its the same with buttons ;)

Hope that helped if not leave a comment.

Comment: YES! Thank you, that is exactly what I was missing...Your a time saver!